# Creating a trigger function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm creating a trigger function that must populate a field called "numero_cip". This field must be fill just one time after a "INSERT ROW", because this field is a join from: "BR" + ID FIELD + SUFIXO FIELD.

So, i'm trying to create this trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numeradora_cip() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE 
 sufixo varchar(2);
 numero_cip varchar(60);
BEGIN 
    sufixo := select p.sufixo from produto p where p.id = NEW.id_produto;
    NEW.numero_cip = select 'BR' || lpad(NEW.id, 11, '0') || sufixo;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

But i got the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 7:     sufixo := select p.sufixo from produto p where p.id = NE...
```

PS: This is my first time creating a trigger function.

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

> **40.5.3. Executing a Query with a Single-row Result**
>
> The result of a SQL command yielding a single row (possibly of multiple columns) can be assigned to a record variable, row-type variable, or list of scalar variables. This is done by writing the base SQL command and adding an `INTO` clause. For example,
>
> > `SELECT select_expressions INTO [STRICT] target FROM ...;`
> >     ...

So you're looking for:

```
select p.sufixo into sufixo from produto p where p.id = NEW.id_produto;
```

And then, since your PL/pgSQL, you can do a simple string concatenation to get your `numero_cip`:

```
NEW.numero_cip := 'BR' || lpad(NEW.id, 11, '0') || sufixo
```

Comment: But the error point to line 7, the line in "SELECT p.sufixo..."

Comment: Because you're saying `sufixo := select ...` when you should be saying `select ... into sufixo ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numeradora_cip() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE 
 sufixo varchar(2);
 numero_cip varchar(60);
BEGIN 
    select p.sufixo into sufixo from produto p where p.id = NEW.id_produto;
    NEW.numero_cip := select 'BR' || lpad(NEW.id, 11, '0') || sufixo;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```